# Laravel Eloquent Eager Loading multiple relationships with pagination

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a site running Laravel 4.2 that I am working on right now, the problem is that I have a single model for orders and another child model for items that belong to the order. The items also have a child model for size information and image information.

I have my query:

```
$orders = Auth::user()->orders()->with('items','items.size','items.image')->get()->toArray();
```

This returns what I am expecting, but I want to have the results paginated using Laravel's pagination. I had expected this to work:

```
$orders = Auth::user()->orders()->with('items','items.size','items.image')->paginate( 10 );
```

This returns a blank white page and a `500 error` and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get this to work correctly.

Here are my various models: `User.php`

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    protected $fillable = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'lat', 'lng', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'hash', 'type', 'blocked', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at' );

    public function setPasswordAttribute( $value ) {
        return $this -> attributes['password'] = Hash::make( $value );
    }

    public function projects() {
        return $this -> belongsToMany('Project');
    }

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('PrintOrder');
    }

    public function bookings() {
        return $this -> belongsToMany('Booking');
    }
}
```

`PrintOrder.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class PrintOrder extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'print_orders';

    protected $fillable = array( 'project_id', 'user_id', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at' );

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany('PrintOrderItem');
    }
}
```

`PrintOrderItem.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class PrintOrderItem extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'print_order_items';

    protected $fillable = array( 'print_order_id', 'upload_id', 'size_id', 'quantity', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at' );

    public function image() {
        return $this->hasOne('Upload','id');
    }

    public function size() {
        return $this->hasOne('PrintSize', 'id');
    }
}
```

`Upload.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Upload extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'uploads';

    protected $fillable = array( 'user_id', 'project_id', 'thumbnail', 'small','medium','large','original','title', 'description','keywords', 'file_type','file_size','file_extension','created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at' );

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('UploadCategory', 'upload_image_categorys');
    }
}
```

`PrintSize.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class PrintSize extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'print_sizes';

    protected $fillable = array( 'title', 'description', 'cost_actual', 'cost_client', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at' );

}
```

Comment: If you're seeing blank page with 500 status code you should probably enable debugging (if you're doing it not on production). I doubt it is not catchable error, so some info should be displayed. Also you can look at log files.

Comment: Ok I will take a look into that, I'm used to using Laravel's built debugging information so I sometimes forget about the logs.